# How to modified SVG file import to KonvaJS?

Tags: svg, canvas, konvajs, konva

i have an issue that's make admin can upload SVG and using it into Drawing Screen use Konva. The way to import that is ok, but ex-function i would like to ask is:

`Is there a ways to help me can change size of that SVG such as inscrease stroke or make it bigger or smaller ?`

Imagine the image below is a SVG i had import and import it to Konva Stage, then i would like to change this stroke to bigger than origin.

[image]

I had research a while but nothing got back, if you have any idea please comment. I'll read it all with all my respect.

Comment: How do you import the SVG into Konva ? If it is as an image then in fact what happens is that the SVG is loaded into a standard plain browser image by browser code, and then the image is handed to Konva. In that case you cannot modify the SVG drawing commands because they are not accessible to Konva, or any lib, in the plain image.

Comment: https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Path.html

Comment: I guess my answer was not what you wanted to hear. However, if it was correct then please mark it as such so that future readers will see it.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: No you can't edit a complex SVG in any practical way.

In the comments you confirmed that you are using the Konva Path object and its superpower to consume an SVG drawing instructions as a string via its data() attribute.

This string is a codified set of data containing the SVG commands such as moveto, lineto, etc.  To give you an idea of the complexity of the string format, [the demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Path.html) on the Konva site which draws a filled green heart looks like this:

```
var path = new Konva.Path({
    x: 50,
    y: 40,
    data: 'M213.1,6.7c-32.4-14.4-73.7,0-88.1,30.6C110.6,4.9,67.5-9.5,36.9,6.7C2.8,22.9-13.4,62.4,13.5,110.9C33.3,145.1,67.5,170.3,125,217c59.3-46.7,93.5-71.9,111.5-106.1C263.4,64.2,247.2,22.9,213.1,6.7z',
    fill: 'green',
    scaleX: 0.5,
    scaleY: 0.5,
});
```

The bad news - there is NO built-in way to access the individual drawing commands encoded in this string within Konva.

You can write your own code to manipulate this string if you wish - change the data string and pass it to the Path via pathObject.data(your_string).

Conclusion: I would look for another lib that *can* achieve this, to use instead or in addition to Konva. I very much like Konva, so my recommendation should underline that to try to edit SVG via mouse -> edit Path.data -> change drawing would be no fun.